# How do I import system01.bdf from another database into my oracle

Tags: oracle

The company's server encountered a virus, and the server administrator reset the server. Luckily, they kept the oracle instance folder, but I didn't know how to extract the data from it.
[This is the legacy oracle instance folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvzNh.png)
[I tried to move system01.dbf directly to my oracle, but failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K79Dt.png)

My English is not very good, this writing is written in Google translation, I hope I can express accurately,thanks.

Comment: If you didn't create new tablespaces, then your data is probably in USERS01.DBF, not SYSTEM01.DBF. But you might just want to copy them all - see this answer on moving datafiles to a new instance. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11706/move-an-oracle-database-by-moving-the-raw-data-files

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will read this blog carefully.